# React not working in my index page for my Flask app?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, reactjs, flask

I'm creating an app, running on the Python framework, Flask. I am trying to use React for the front end, and am including it in my index.html file that my flask app loads. However, in my text editor, the jsx code is not highlighted, and nothing appears when I load my flask app.

I get no error messages. I even get the message about getting react dev tools in my browser console. But no React output.

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">

    <title>Web App</title>

    <!-- Style for our table of data that we will display -->
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: navy;
    }
    table {
        background-color: azure;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table tr td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    table td + td {
        border-left: 2px solid lightseagreen;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Load jQuery and React -->
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin = "anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!-- If that fails, we have a backup in our directory-->
    <script type = text/javascript src = "{{
        url_for('static', filename = 'jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script type = text/javascript src = "{{
        url_for('static', filename = 'react.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type = text/javascript src = "{{
        url_for('static', filename = 'react-dom.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Form for submitting our NBA Data-->
    <form id = "nameForm" role = "form">
        <!-- Input box so we can search by player name -->
        <input name = "text">
        <!-- Button that we will use to make the actual ajax call -->
        <button id = "searchBtn"> Search </button>
    </form>

    <script type = "text/jsx">
        var realPython = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (<h2> Greetings, from me </h2>);
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(realPython, null),
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
    </script>

    <!-- Container that we will add our data table to later -->
    <div id = "container"></div>

    <!-- Script for the button click action -->
    <script type = text/javascript> 
    //Root stuff
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};

        //Root so we can get the data from our form
        $('button#searchBtn').click(function(e) {
            //Prevent our form from submitting, which is its default action/purpose
            e.preventDefault();
            //Get the data from our function in the Flask App
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_data', {
                //Our searchName variable will be the one from our HTML input box
                searchName: $('input[name = "text"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
                //Rename the variable so I can reuse some code 
                var data_list = data.dataList;
                //Headers for our tables second row
                var titles = data.headers;
            });
        }); 
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are appending in `content` element, but in the body, there is no container which has `content ` id

Comment: @Thinker I tried using this ```<div id = 'content'></div>

    <script type = "text/jsx">
        var realPython = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (<h2> Greetings, from me </h2>);
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(realPython, null),
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
    </script>``` And still not luck